# Greatest Common Superclass

Tags: python, superclass

Is there any simple way to get the "greatest common superclass" of a list of objects? For example, if

```
class A(object): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(B, C): pass
class E(C): pass
class F(D, E): pass
```

and

```
b = B()
d = D()
e = E()
```

then

```
gcs(b, e) is A
gcs(d, e) is C
gcs(e, e) is E
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Martijn's idea, but using an easier approach considering that time complexity is not going to be an issue here(Thanks to @veedrac for his inputs):

```
def gcs(*instances):
    classes = [type(x).mro() for x in instances]
    for x in classes[0]:
        if all(x in mro for mro in classes):
            return x

print gcs(b, e)
print gcs(d, e)
print gcs(e, e)
```

**Output:**

```
<class '__main__.A'>
<class '__main__.C'>
<class '__main__.E'>
```

A slight variant of the above code using sets:

```
def gcs(*instances):
    mros = (type(ins).mro() for ins in instances)
    mro = next(mros)
    common = set(mro).intersection(*mros)
    return next((x for x in mro if x in common), None)
```

Comment: To make search more effective one may use binary search as `__mro__` is sorted.

Comment: @Vladimir No, `__mro__` is not sorted at all. MRO contains different types and their comparison can result in arbitrary result. You can try comparing `sorted()` version of `__mro__` and the actual `__mro__` to verify. Though I've added another version that makes use of sets.

Comment: Is there really any point getting `smallest` in that second example? iterating over `mros[0]` is probably faster, and the code ends up cleaner because you can unpack. Also, you should probably use `.mro()` instead of `.__mro__`.

Comment: @Veedrac Good point, I think it is not required in first one either as the new C3 algorithm makes sure that the monotonicity is always maintained. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially a simplified longest-common-subsequence problem; compare the MRO sequences and return the type with the lowest sum of their indices:

```
def gcs(a, b):
    """Find the common base class between two classes or instances"""
    try:
        a, b = a.mro(), b.mro()
    except AttributeError:
        a, b = type(a).mro(), type(b).mro()
    a_idx, b_idx = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(a)}, {t: i for i, t in enumerate(b)}
    try:
        return min(a_idx.viewkeys() & b_idx.viewkeys(),
                   key=lambda t: a_idx[t] + b_idx[t])
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

This is a O(M+N) algorithm, where M and N are the sizes of the MROs of both objects. The function can handle both classes and instances.

Demo with your sample objects:

```
>>> gcs(e, b)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> gcs(e, d)
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> gcs(e, e)
<class '__main__.E'>
```

Comment: In fact, that makes me think that something is not so well defined in my question, as the `gcs` is not always unique...

Comment: Wouldn't you want the *last* common element in the MRO if you want "greatest" common superclass? And wouldn't this be `object` for all of these?

Comment: Perhaps you can call it 'lowest' then. I wasn't sure what's the proper term in this case.

Comment: @Bach: I gave you a greatest common superclass; if you want the 'lowest above object' then you'll have to return `res[1]` instead (presuming that `res[0]` is `object`).

Comment: @Martijn: I think there might be a bug in the code. Permuting the bases of a class should not affect the "greatest common superclass". For example, if `class D(C, B): pass` instead of `class D(B, C): pass`, then `gse(d, e)` incorrectly returns `A` instead of `C`.

Comment: @unutbu: yeah, there is a bug, looking for a better approach to efficiently find a 'first' matching element.

Comment: @unutbu: better? Now I map classes to indices, then find the lowest index for a match in the other MRO. Still working out what that means if you swap the two.

Comment: It looks better. However, if we define `class D(B, C): pass`, and `class D2(C, B): pass`, then `gcs(D, D2)` returns `B`, while `gcs(D2, D)` returns `C`.

Comment: @unutbu: in that case the 'greatest common' is ambiguous.

Comment: @unutbu: However, for `G(B, C, A)` and `H(A, F, C)` it'll now consistently list `A`, not `C`, because `C` sits further back in `H`.

Comment: Not sure about that last point. Wouldn't `H(A, F, C)` raise a TypeError since A can't come before C? In any case, do you know if there is a graph-theoretic concept which would help define 'greatest common' to be commutative, so that `gcs(D, D2) = gcs(D2, D) = set([B, C])`?

Comment: @unutbu: sorry, I only worked that one out on paper as an MRO only, not actually constructing classes. In other words, I ignored the existing class definitions here.

Comment: @unutbu: so I have MROs of `(E A F C object)` and `(G B C A object)`, then the matrix between these two has A closer to the origin than C.

Comment: @unutbu: refactored to be more efficient and also stable for your `D, D2` case.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem here is that you can have more than one greatest common superclass -- take a class inheritance structure such as

```
AB ---> A
   \ /
    x
   / \
BA ---> B
```

In this case, both `A` and `B` are legitimate answers to `gca([AB, BA])`.

After encountering that in my own code, I realized I needed to reframe the question into:

> Find the minimal set of common bases shared by a specified class list; defined as all classes which 1) are a parent class of everything in original list, and 2) have NO subclasses that are also included in the returned list.
>
> This last requirement takes care of getting only the "nearest" class, yet handles the case where there are multiple such values.

The following code implements this:

```
def minimal_common_bases(classes):
    # pull first class, and start with it's bases
    gen = iter(classes)
    cls = next(gen, None)
    if cls is None:
        return set()
    common = set(cls.__mro__)

    # find set of ALL ancestor classes,
    # by intersecting MROs of all specified classes
    for cls in gen:
        common.intersection_update(cls.__mro__)

    # remove any bases which have at least one subclass also in the set,
    # as they aren't part of "minimal" set of common ancestors.
    result = common.copy()
    for cls in common:
        if cls in result:
            result.difference_update(cls.__mro__[1:])

    # return set
    return result
```

- NOTE: under py2, you'll need to use `inspect.getmro(cls)` instead of `cls.__mro__`.